# Edit condition in BASH

Tags: bash

why does not work this condition?

```
if [ -d /home/virt -a $(ls -A /home/virt/) = 0 ]
```

Exists of directory /home/virt AND check if the directory is /home/virt/ empty

Thank you...

Comment: look at the output of `ls -A /home/virt/` when it's NOT empty ... OR for that matter if empty, then result is equiv to "", not 0. Won't work. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [ -d $1 -a $(ls -A $1 | wc -l) == 0 ]; then
  echo EMPTY
fi
```